# jQuery slider start position

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slide.js

Some time ago I copied some slider code from some website. Can't find where is it now.
The code is:

```
slides.min.jquery.js

$(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        play: 12000,
        pause: 8000,
        hoverPause: true,
        generatePagination: false
    });
});
```

The slider works well. But, my problem now is, I want the slider to start at random slide position. For example, it can randomly start at slide 5, or slide 3, or slide 4; on each refresh.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your using [slide.js](http://www.slidesjs.com/#examples) the documentation specifies you can set the start slide by including the `start` property in the settings.

```
$(function(){
    var EXCLUSIVE_UPPER_BOUNDS = 5; //adjust for your app
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        play: 12000,
        pause: 8000,
        hoverPause: true,
        generatePagination: false,
        start: Math.floor(Math.random()* EXCLUSIVE_UPPER_BOUNDS)
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, this works great. Don't need that semicolon (;) though.Thanks.

Comment: @JK Glad, I could help, good catch on the semi, I modified the solution to reflect.

Comment: Assuming your slide elements are all children of `#slides` element you could probably calculate the upper bounds with `$('#slides').children().length`.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the slider slides in random order on every page load.
Or you DOM manipulation to sort them in random order and place them again in their parent container.
Then use your javascript to initiate the slider.

eg.:

```
<div id='slides' >
 <img src='image_a' />
 <img src='image_b' />
 <img src='image_c' />
 <img src='image_d' />
</div>
```

It is trivial to convert this into :

```
<div id='slides' >
 <img src='image_b' />
 <img src='image_a' />
 <img src='image_d' />
 <img src='image_c' />
</div>
```

Using DOM manipulation or shuffling at backend script.